# Parse specific data from xml in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, xml-parsing

I want to know how to parse specific data from my xml-file in Android Studio. Please write the commands to parse the strings.
The information I need are:

1. first day of the year
2. all countries (e. g. "GB" and "US")
3. begin ("From") and end ("To") of the holiday "summer" in GB
4. all cities of the US
5. name of the holidays in the US
6. the name of the capitol ("Washington") and the inhabitants of the capitol in the US

**My xml-file named "file.xml":**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <data>
        <dates>
            <days>monday, tuesday, wednesdaywednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday</days>
            <FirstDayOfTheYear>2021/01/01</FirstDayOfTheYear>
            <LastDayOfTheYear>2021/12/31</LastDayOfTheYear>
        </dates>
        <countries>
            <country>
                <name>GB</name>
                <holidays>
                    <holi From="2021/03/06" To="2021/03/12">winter</holi>
                    <holi From="2021/06/16" To="2021/06/17">summer</holi>
                    <holi From="2021/12/12" To="2021/12/24">christmas</holi>
                </holidays>
                <cities>
                    <city>
                        <name>London</name>
                        <capital>yes</capital>
                        <inhabitants>8,982,000</inhabitants>
                    </city>
                    <city>
                        <name>Oxford</name>
                        <capital>no</capital>
                        <inhabitants>152,450</inhabitants>
                    </city>
                    <city>
                        <name>Liverpool</name>
                        <capital>no</capital>
                        <inhabitants>496,784</inhabitants>
                    </city>
                </cities>
            </country>
            <country>
                <name>US</name>
                <holidays>
                    <holi From="2021/04/06" To="2021/04/14">spring</holi>
                    <holi From="2021/07/18" To="2021/07/25">summer</holi>
                    <holi From="2021/12/12" To="2021/12/27">christmas</holi>
                </holidays>
                <cities>
                    <city>
                        <name>Washington, D.C.</name>
                        <capital>yes</capital>
                        <inhabitants>692,683</inhabitants>
                    </city>
                    <city>
                        <name>New York</name>
                        <capital>no</capital>
                        <inhabitants>8,419,000</inhabitants>
                    </city>
                    <city>
                        <name>Detroit</name>
                        <capital>no</capital>
                        <inhabitants>674,841</inhabitants>
                    </city>
                </cities>
            </country>
        </countries>
    </data>
```

**My MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.xml;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.xml");

            XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser myParser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

            myParser.setInput(is, null);

            int event = myParser.getEventType();
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)  {


                if (event == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

                    // TODO: Your code here

                }
                event = myParser.next();
            }

            tv1.setText("");    // Display the result

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tv1.setText(e.toString());
        }
    }

    static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
        NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = nodeList.item(0);
        return node.getNodeValue();
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World!"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And... What is the problem? What are the questions? Put all in your post please.

Comment: I want to know the commands to parse the data I need (see above).

Comment: Please don't ask people to write code for you. Explain what you tried and how it failed, and then we'll try to show you where you went wrong so that you can get it right next time.

Comment: But I don't know how to do it. If you know a good tutorial it'll be okay for me too.